# How to subtract rows in xts with multiple columns

Tags: r, xts

How do you subtract a single row of data in an xts object from the entire (multi-row), xts object?

**MWE**

```
require(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
x-coredata(x['2007-06-09'])[1,]
```

From the output, R has taken the row vector, stripped of its context, and subtracted it by recycling across the columns.

E.g. if I were using the following xts object in place of x

```
a1 b1 c1 d1
a2 b2 c2 d2
```

And made the following subtraction

```
x-coredata(x[2,])[1,]
```

The result would be

```
a1-a2 b1-c2 c1-a2 d1-c2 
a2-b2 b2-d2 c2-b2     0
```

My intended output:

```
a1-a2 b1-b2 c1-c2 d1-d2
    0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale()`

```
data(sample_matrix)
x <- tail(as.xts(sample_matrix), 5)

scale(x, center=unlist(tail(x, 1)), scale=FALSE)

#                    Open       High         Low      Close
# 2007-06-26 -0.231679339 -0.3251569 -0.23167934 -0.1510840
# 2007-06-27 -0.051446746 -0.2245367 -0.07452939 -0.1395032
# 2007-06-28  0.001354599 -0.2366639 -0.10227449 -0.1600355
# 2007-06-29 -0.038391981 -0.1656322 -0.05735147 -0.1024815
# 2007-06-30  0.000000000  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `xts` inherits from `zoo` which has a numerical matrix under the hood, we can take advantage of all the usual `matrix` operations:

```
library(xts)
set.seed(911)
myXts <- xts(cbind(rnorm(5), rnorm(5)), seq(as.Date("2017-10-22"), length.out = 5, by = 1))

myXts - 5 # subtracts 5 from every cell
sweep(myXts, 2, c(5, 1)) # subtracts 5 from col 1, and 1 from col 2 (all rows)
myXts[2, ] <- myXts[2, ] - c(5, 1) # subtract only from row 2 and replace the existing
```